# How to make search results appear on another page?

Tags: php, search

I have a big search on my home-page and when the user types in the text fields and clicks submit I want the results from my database to appear on another site in this case 'searchresults.php.' In this case 'really.html' is my homepage.

Here is my code:

What am I doing wrong?

Really.html

```
<center>
<form action="searchresults.php" method="post">
<input type="text" size="35" value="Job Title e.g. Assistant Manager" 
style="background-    color:white; border: 
solid 1px #6E6E6E; height: 30px; font-size:18px; 
vertical-align:9px;color:#bbb" 
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Job Title e.g. Assistant Manager'){this.value = 
'';this.style.color='#000'}" />
<input type="text" size="35" value="Location e.g. Manchester"
style="background-    color:white; border: 
solid 1px #6E6E6E; height: 30px; font-size:18px; 
vertical-align:9px;color:#bbb" 
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Location e.g. Manchester'){this.value = 
'';this.style.color='#000'}" />
<input type="image" src="but.tiff" alt="Submit" width="60">
</form>
```

Searchresults.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if(strlen(trim($_POST['search'])) > 0) {
//all of your php code for the search

$search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
$searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";

    mysql_connect ("", "", "");
      mysql_select_db ("");
    if (!empty($_POST["search_string"])) 
    { 

    }  

  $query = "SELECT name,location,msg FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '$search' AND 
location      LIKE '$searchterm'";

  $result = mysql_query ($query);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
      echo "<br>$row[0]<br>";
      echo "$row[1]<br>";
      echo "$row[2]<br>";
    }
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I dont get any errors its just blank with nothing on the page for searchresults.php

Comment: Do i i have to split the php code and put some in really.html?

Comment: Either check your error log or set display errors to 1: `ini_set( 'display_errors',1);`

Comment: @James: enable PHP's error reporting. You will find out that there is an error on the page.

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); var_dump($_POST);` to the top of searchresults.php so we can see an example value you're passing there and any errors you're getting.

Comment: Learn to write better markups, break out your inline css and js into separate files. I really don't feel like reading your code. It's very messy.

Comment: array(2) { ["x"]=> string(1) "0" ["y"]=> string(1) "0" } 
Notice: Undefined index: search in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage21/fo/ur/wa/fourwaysdp.co.uk/public_html/searchresults.php on line 6

Comment: if(strlen(trim($_POST['search'])) > 0) { 


Which is this line ^^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is probably returning 0 results. Instead of

```
if ($result) {
```

Try

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
```

And in your query try...

```
$query = "SELECT name,location,msg FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' AND 
location      LIKE '%$searchterm%'";
```

This will be less strict and return a better result set.

Answer (score 1):

You should add attr **name** to your input.
For example,

```
<input type="text" name="search" ... />

<input type="text" name="searchterm" ... />
```

Also don't forget about escaping input data using mysqL_escape_string function

Comment: But now:

array(4) { ["search"]=> string(7) "trainee" ["searchterm"]=> string(6) "london" ["x"]=> string(1) "7" ["y"]=> string(2) "17" } 

is returned at the top of the page with the results

How do I stop this?

Comment: It seems that you run var_dump($_POST);